# scrapy doesnt compile

Tags: installation, scrapy

I use MacOS 10.7.3 and XCode 4.3. In order to install Scrapy, I have followed the instructions here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/install.html#download-and-install-an-official-release .

But unfortunately the command `python setup.py install` failed:

```
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually run the Xcode installer, found in /Applications? Getting it via the MacAppStore doesn't install it automatically.